How to calculate the click on the original pixel of the image after it has been panned, zoomed, and adjusted with the scrollbars
Issue
I am created a GridEditor program that generates a grid based on the dimensions provided and then allows you to paint patterns in each of these grid squares. I implemented a zoom and pan method based on the answer in this stackoverflow. Note I did change the zoom values to work on a mac. For now I have been able to convert any zoom scaling and draging within the screen to the original pixel location.
I have two issues: if the user uses the scrollbar and drags the view, and if the user uses their mouse to pan the canvas beyond on the visibile range.
Here is the link to the image here
Here is the code for the zooming method.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

import tkmacosx
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageDraw


class ImageCanvas(tk.Canvas):

    def __init__(self, parent, grid_image: Image):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, parent)

        self.image = None
        self._image = grid_image.convert("RGBA")

        self.grid(column=0, row=0)  #add canvas to frame

    def click(self, x, y):
        if(not (x < 0 or x > self._image.width or y < 0 or y > self._image.height)):
            print('Clicked ({}, {})'.format(x, y))
            self.drawSquare(x, y)
        else: print('clicked outside image')

    def drawSquare(self, x, y):
        square = Image.new(self._image.mode, self._image.size, (0, 0, 0, 0))
        square_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(square)
        square_draw.rectangle((x, y, x+10, y+10), outline='black', fill='magenta')
        self._image.alpha_composite(square)

    def return_image(self):
        return self._image


class AutoScrollbar(ttk.Scrollbar):
    """ A scrollbar that hides itself if it's not needed. Works only for grid geometry manager """
    def set(self, lo, hi):
        if float(lo) <= 0.0 and float(hi) >= 1.0:
            self.grid_remove()
        else:
            self.grid()
            ttk.Scrollbar.set(self, lo, hi)

    def pack(self, **kw):
        raise tk.TclError('Cannot use pack with the widget ' + self.__class__.__name__)

    def place(self, **kw):
        raise tk.TclError('Cannot use place with the widget ' + self.__class__.__name__)


class CanvasImage():
    """ Display and zoom image """

    def __init__(self, placeholder, path):
        """ Initialize the ImageFrame """
        self.imscale = 1.0  # scale for the canvas image zoom, public for outer classes
        self.__delta = 1.3  # zoom magnitude
        self.__filter = Image.Resampling.LANCZOS  # could be: NEAREST, BILINEAR, BICUBIC and ANTIALIAS
        #self.__previous_state = 0  # previous state of the keyboard
        # Create ImageFrame in placeholder widget
        self.__imframe = ttk.Frame(placeholder)  # placeholder of the ImageFrame object

        #Drawing mode
        self.drawing_mode = True

        #Pan mode
        self.panning_mode = False
        # Panning offsets
        self.pan_offset_x = 0
        self.pan_offset_y = 0

        # Vertical and horizontal scrollbars for canvas
        hbar = AutoScrollbar(self.__imframe, orient='horizontal')
        vbar = AutoScrollbar(self.__imframe, orient='vertical')
        hbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='we')
        vbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')

        # Create canvas and bind it with scrollbars. Public for outer classes
        # Create my own canvas and put image on it
        img = Image.open(path)
        self.canvas = ImageCanvas(self.__imframe, img)
        self.canvas.config(highlightthickness=0, xscrollcommand=hbar.set, yscrollcommand=vbar.set)

        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nswe')
        self.canvas.update()  # wait till canvas is created
        hbar.configure(command=self.__scroll_x)  # bind scrollbars to the canvas
        vbar.configure(command=self.__scroll_y)

        # Bind events to the Canvas
        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda event: self.__show_image())  # canvas is resized
        self.canvas.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.__move_from)  # remember canvas position
        self.canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.__move_to)  # move canvas to the new position
        self.canvas.bind('<MouseWheel>', self.__wheel)  # zoom for MacOS

        self.__image = img # open image, but don't load it
        self.imwidth, self.imheight = self.__image.size  # public for outer classes

        # Put image into container rectangle and use it to set proper coordinates to the image
        self.container = self.canvas.create_rectangle((0, 0, self.imwidth, self.imheight), width=0)
        self.__show_image()  # show image on the canvas
        self.canvas.focus_set()  # set focus on the canvas

    def click(self, event):
        if (self.drawing_mode):
            # Get the coordinates of the click relative to the canvas
            canvas_x = event.x
            canvas_y = event.y
            print('og', canvas_x)

            # Subtract the accumulated panning offset from the click coordinates
            canvas_x -= self.pan_offset_x
            canvas_y -= self.pan_offset_y
            print('new', canvas_x)

            # Get the bounding box of the image on the canvas
            bbox = self.canvas.coords(self.container)
            image_width = bbox[2] - bbox[0]
            image_height = bbox[3] - bbox[1]
            #print(image_width, image_height)

            # Calculate the scale and offset due to zooming and panning
            scale = self.imscale
            offset_x = bbox[0] / scale
            offset_y = bbox[1] / scale

            # Calculate the coordinates of the click on the original image
            image_x = int((canvas_x / scale) - offset_x)
            image_y = int((canvas_y / scale) - offset_y)
            print("({}, {})".format(canvas_x, canvas_y))
            #print("({}, {})".format(image_x, image_y))

            #Click original coordinates
            self.canvas.click(image_x, image_y)

            #Place Image
            self.__image = self.canvas.return_image()

            #Show Image
            self.__show_image()

            '''Remember to add in fixing the panning issue. Subtract panned movement'''

    def redraw_figures(self):
        """ Dummy function to redraw figures in the children classes """
        pass

    def __scroll_x(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Scroll canvas horizontally and update the panning offset """
        self.canvas.xview(*args)  # scroll horizontally
        self.__show_image()  # redraw the image

    def __scroll_y(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Scroll canvas vertically and update the panning offset """
        self.canvas.yview(*args)  # scroll vertically
        self.__show_image()  # redraw the image

    def __show_image(self):
        """ Show image on the Canvas. Implements correct image zoom almost like in Google Maps """
        box_image = self.canvas.coords(self.container)  # get image area
        box_canvas = (self.canvas.canvasx(0),  # get visible area of the canvas
                      self.canvas.canvasy(0),
                      self.canvas.canvasx(self.canvas.winfo_width()),
                      self.canvas.canvasy(self.canvas.winfo_height()))
        box_img_int = tuple(map(int, box_image))  # convert to integer or it will not work properly
        # Get scroll region box
        box_scroll = [min(box_img_int[0], box_canvas[0]), min(box_img_int[1], box_canvas[1]),
                      max(box_img_int[2], box_canvas[2]), max(box_img_int[3], box_canvas[3])]
        # Horizontal part of the image is in the visible area
        if box_scroll[0] == box_canvas[0] and box_scroll[2] == box_canvas[2]:
            box_scroll[0] = box_img_int[0]
            box_scroll[2] = box_img_int[2]
        # Vertical part of the image is in the visible area
        if box_scroll[1] == box_canvas[1] and box_scroll[3] == box_canvas[3]:
            box_scroll[1] = box_img_int[1]
            box_scroll[3] = box_img_int[3]
        # Convert scroll region to tuple and to integer
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=tuple(map(int, box_scroll)))  # set scroll region
        x1 = max(box_canvas[0] - box_image[0], 0)  # get coordinates (x1,y1,x2,y2) of the image tile
        y1 = max(box_canvas[1] - box_image[1], 0)
        x2 = min(box_canvas[2], box_image[2]) - box_image[0]
        y2 = min(box_canvas[3], box_image[3]) - box_image[1]

        if int(x2 - x1) > 0 and int(y2 - y1) > 0:  # show image if it in the visible area
            x = min(int(x2 / self.imscale), self.imwidth)  # sometimes it is larger on 1 pixel...
            y = min(int(y2 / self.imscale), self.imheight)  # ...and sometimes not
            image = self.__image.crop((int(x1 / self.imscale), int(y1 / self.imscale), x, y))
            imagetk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.resize((int(x2 - x1), int(y2 - y1))))
            imageid = self.canvas.create_image(max(box_canvas[0], box_img_int[0]),
                                               max(box_canvas[1], box_img_int[1]),
                                               anchor='nw', image=imagetk)

            self.canvas.lower(imageid)  # set image into background
            self.canvas.imagetk = imagetk  # keep an extra reference to prevent garbage-collection

    def __move_from(self, event):
        if(self.panning_mode):
            """ Remember previous coordinates for scrolling with the mouse """
            self.canvas.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)

            #Store panning clicks
            self.prev_x = event.x
            self.prev_y = event.y

        self.click(event)  #call my function to get info

    def __move_to(self, event):
        if(self.panning_mode):
            #Panning store calculations
            delta_x = event.x - self.prev_x
            delta_y = event.y - self.prev_y
            self.prev_x = event.x
            self.prev_y = event.y

            # Update the accumulated panning offset
            self.pan_offset_x += delta_x
            self.pan_offset_y += delta_y

            """ Drag (move) canvas to the new position """
            self.canvas.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1)
            self.__show_image()  # zoom tile and show it on the canvas

    def outside(self, x, y):
        """ Checks if the point (x,y) is outside the image area """
        bbox = self.canvas.coords(self.container)  # get image area
        if bbox[0] < x < bbox[2] and bbox[1] < y < bbox[3]:
            return False  # point (x,y) is inside the image area
        else:
            return True  # point (x,y) is outside the image area

    def __wheel(self, event):
        """ Zoom with mouse wheel """
        x = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)  # get coordinates of the event on the canvas
        y = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
        if self.outside(x, y): return  # zoom only inside image area
        scale = 1.0
        # Respond to Mac wheel event
        if event.num == 5 or event.delta < 0:  # scroll down, smaller
            i = min(self.imwidth, self.imheight)
            if int(i * self.imscale) < 30: return  # image is less than 30 pixels
            self.imscale /= self.__delta
            scale /= self.__delta
        if event.num == 4 or event.delta > 0:  # scroll up, bigger
            i = min(self.canvas.winfo_width(), self.canvas.winfo_height())
            if i < self.imscale: return  # 1 pixel is bigger than the visible area
            self.imscale *= self.__delta
            scale *= self.__delta
        self.canvas.scale('all', x, y, scale, scale)  # rescale all objects
        # Redraw some figures before showing image on the screen
        self.redraw_figures()  # method for child classes
        self.__show_image()

    def enable(self, input_string: str):
        if (input_string == 'draw'):
            self.panning_mode = False
            self.drawing_mode = True
        if (input_string == 'pan'):
            self.panning_mode = True
            self.drawing_mode = False
        print('Draw status: ', self.drawing_mode)
        print('Panning status: ', self.panning_mode)

    def grid(self, **kw):
        """ Put CanvasImage widget on the parent widget """
        self.__imframe.grid(**kw)  # place CanvasImage widget on the grid
        self.__imframe.grid(sticky='nswe')  # make frame container sticky
        self.__imframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)  # make canvas expandable
        self.__imframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def destroy(self):
        """ ImageFrame destructor """
        self.__image.close()
        self.canvas.destroy()
        self.__imframe.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Grid Editor Test')
    root.geometry('800x800')
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)  # make the CanvasImage widget expandable
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    # add GridEditor
    img_path = 'Grid8by10.jpeg'
    canvas = CanvasImage(root, img_path)  # create widget
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='nwse')  # show widget

    pan_btn = tkmacosx.Button(root, text='Pan', command=lambda:canvas.enable('pan'))
    zoom_btn = tkmacosx.Button(root, text='Draw', command=lambda:canvas.enable('draw'))

    pan_btn.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsw' )
    zoom_btn.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nse')

    root.mainloop()


The solutions I have come up with are:
If the user uses the scrollbar I figured first I would use a prev_scroll_x var and a current var to calculate amount scrolled by intercepting the *args statement and grabing the percent of image viewed now. Then I could multiply that percent by the image width and get the amount of pixels the image shifted. Seems like it could maybe work, but I have struggled to implement it.
For the canvas beyond the visible range, I honestly don't really have a solution for because I can't seem to fully wrap my head around the bbox's and how they interact with the zooming. I know I shouldn't use code I understand, but I can't really find someone to explain it. I did reach out to the person who created the original code on twitter to ask questions, but no response. Also, that is completely fair because it was like 2018 when it was posted.
I tried doing the scrollbar thing I mentioned above but I haven't gotten it right yet, so I am looking for feedback on how I could do that.
I also tried to use canvasx and canvasy but it returned points that were always way off.

If you post the entire code and the image so that it is possible to see what it does it would be sure way easier to help you.

@Claudio Okay you are right that would be helpful. I didn't want to just post my whole program so I made a minimum viable running demonstration that shows the issue. The draw button is what allows you to place squares the pan button allows you to drag canvas. I am posting the new code now and adding the image similar to what I would be working with.
